# C# OpenFiledialog.Showdialog giving error CS1061

Tags: c#

When I try to call openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); it gives me an error CS1061

My friend used similiar code and it worked for him any idea whats wrong with mine?

Googled alot tried alot of things nothing payed out

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Load List";
            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); //Error CS1061 here
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            List<string> accounts = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Lines Loaded: " + accounts.Count);
            Console.Write("Threads : ");
```

Comment: You must be missing an assembly reference or a using (Microsoft.Win32)  statement. Are you running WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Include on the *csthml the nameSpaces that contains that Extension Method.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the STAThread attribute (Indicates that the COM Threading model Single Threaded Appartment, required if you interact with Windows system components) to the entry point of your code main in case of console application, below an example:

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Load List";
            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); //Error CS1061 here
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            List<string> accounts = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Lines Loaded: " + accounts.Count);
            Console.Write("Threads : ");
        }
```